# Using RGBDSLAM in gazebo environment?

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm thinking about using RGBDSLAM in gazebo environment.
If I set up an indoor environment and a robot with kinect in gazebo, how can I implement
SLAM for this simulated environment? For example, I'm wondering how to start up the node RGBDSLAM in gazebo.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32963/using-rgbdslam-in-gazebo-environment?/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wouldn't it work just as in reality? I have a simulator with kinect support and it works. Except that everything looks the same and therefore the feature matches are really bad :-).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1